# How can I get the proper output with this Perl program?

Tags: perl

I have a problem with a regular expression. I am 
trying to extract the multiple conditions inside `while` and `if`. I am using Perl 5.8.6 on Windows XP.

`@conditions` is an array that exactly contains the while loop contents, e.g.:

```
while
 (
    (condition A) &&
    (condition B)
 )
```

You can assume `@conditions` array contains the above data:

```
my perl code sampled:

my $count = 0; 
foreach my $condition (@conditions) { 
    $count++; 
    my ($open,$close) = $condition =~ /( (?: [(] | \s )* ) (.*) /msx; 
    print "$open $count $close"; 
    }
```

and my C code:

```
 while
 (
   ( 
    1 condition A &&
    2 condition B
   )&&
   (
    3 condition C
    4 condition D
   )
 )
```

I am facing the problem when I have a while loop like this:

```
while
 (

     (condition A) &&
     (condition B)
 )
```

My desired output has to be:

```
 while
 (

    1 (condition A) &&
    2 (condition B)
 )
```

but it prints has...

```
while
(
   ( 1 condition A) &&
   ( 2 condition B)

)
```

Can anyone help me with the regex to get my desired output?

Comment: What is the relationship between the "C" code and the variable `@conditions`? How does `@conditions` get initialized? It'll be hard to get the desired output without knowing what the input is.

Comment: Similar question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938821

Answer (score 2):

You have `print "$open $count $close";` and you state that you want the number to preceed the parenthesis.

So use `print "$count $open$close";`

Comment: no its wrong..acc to you it will print as
 while 
1( 
 2  (condition A) && 
  3 (  condition B) 
 ) 
its totaly wrong...

Comment: My code prints a space between the numeral and the opening parenthesis. Show what code you're actually using, because it's not the same.