# How can I match certain nested parentheses in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

`^\s*[)]*\s*$`  and `^\s*[(]*\s*$` matches the parentheses `(` and `)` which are bold. That is, what am trying is to ignore parentheses that are single and not (condition1) parentheses:

```
while
   (    #matches here
     (  #matches here
      (condition1) && (condition2) && 
       condition3 
    ) || 
    (#matches here
      (condition4) || 
       condition5 && 
       (condition6) 
     ) #matches here

  ) #matches here
```

but if I have like this it does not match:

```
while
 (( #does not match here
      (condition1) && (condition2) && 
       condition3 
    ) || 
    (
      (condition4) || 
       condition5 && 
       (condition6) 
     ) ) #does not match here
```

or

```
while
 ((( #does not match here
      (condition1) && (condition2) && 
       condition3 
    )) || 
    ((  #does not match here
      (condition4) || 
       condition5 && 
       (condition6) 
     ) ) ) #does not match here
```

How can I match all the parentheses that are single?

Comment: So basically you wanna match all the parenthesis except the inner most ones, am I right?

Comment: You should really use a parser. Regular expressions can not be used to express non-regular languages like yours.

Comment: I'm sure one of the perl gods can do it given the fact that PCREs are not really regular expressions in the mathematical sense. However, it's a recipe for unmaintainable, unreadable brittle code.

Comment: Warning, question already repeated twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938821 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102462

Comment: Perhaps you should explain your task to us. You're presenting a bit of the XY Problem (http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341). We might be able to suggest a better way to do what you need to accomplish if we knew what it was.

Answer (score 5):

I'd personally recommend that you use a simple stack to figure out open and closing brackets rather than trip over regular expressions.

Comment: Also, normal parser are needed, not just bracket counter.

Comment: Not *really* if you don't care about quoted/escaped brackets. You just need a simple stack and counter.